# how to set imeg overlaying spinner list item?

Tags: android

i am using spinner to display month List.

but
i wanna to set a images to overlaying month list? but i am nt founded any Exact solution.

Comment: I think you want to display month name with an image in a list item..?

Like this : [Image   MonthName] ? is it what you are asking ?

Comment: spinner show list item inside a default box,i want to display all month's name within an inside a single image , means replace default box

Comment: Do you want to display only images in the list ? Or you want to overlay text on image ?

Comment: Can you please give an example what you want to do. I am not getting what you actually want ?

Comment: ok , i m using spinner , that show all months. spinner show the result inside a dailog or popup, i wanna to set image in place of dailog boxes or popup.

Comment: if u have any idea  plz share me, i m new commer in android,

Comment: Ok. when you click on spinner item, it should display me an image related to clicked item frm spinner right ? And yaa where the image is to be displayed ? Below Spinner ?

Comment: yes exactly, display imaeg  below the spinner. and my image store in drawble.

Answer (score 1):

Spinner.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />        
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myimgview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity Class must look like this :

```
package my.co.home;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class ViewsActivity extends Activity 
{
String[] presidents = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "December"
};

Spinner s1;
ImageView ivl;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    //startActivity(new Intent(this, SpinnerActivity.class));

    s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ivl=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimgview);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, presidents);

    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
        View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            //Depending on index you display the image..For example i have taken for //two indexes
            if(index==1)
                ivl.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images));
            else if(index==2)
                ivl.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.images1));
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
    });

}
}
```

Comment: thanks Kartik, bt i want to display all records in side a single imeg.

Comment: What kind of records ? and what kind of image? n where you want to display ?

Comment: is your query solved ?..why you marked this post unsolved after marking it solved ?

Comment: sory dear , it my mistake , i could'nt explain to u properly.  i wanna papulate month list in a single imeg.plz read our previous conversion.